# Use environment variables in CMD

Tags: environment-variables, docker

Can I use environment variables in my CMD stanza in a Dockerfile?

I want to do something like this:

```
CMD ["myserver", "--arg=$ARG", "--memcache=$MEMCACHE_11211_TCP_ADDR:$MEMCACHE_11211_TCP_PORT"]
```

Where $MEMCACHE_11211_TCP_* would be set automatically by the inclusion of the --link parameter of my `docker run` command.  And $ARG would be configurable by the user at runtime, maybe by the "-e" parameter?

This doesn't seem to be working for me, it seems to be literally passing through the string "$ARG" for example.

Answer (score 81):

This answer may be a little late. But environment for `CMD` is interpreted slightly differently depending on how you write the arguments. If you pass the `CMD` as a string (not inside an array), it gets launched as a shell instead of exec. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd.

You may try the `CMD` without the array syntax to run as a shell:

```
CMD myserver --arg=$ARG --memcache=$MEMCACHE_11211_TCP_ADDR:$MEMCACHE_11211_TCP_PORT
```

Comment: If you use the `CMD string` approach though, it's possible that `Ctrl-C` will stop working when you use `docker run my-image` because the shell gets the interrupt instead of the process being started by `CMD`.

Answer (score 45):

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo ${MY_HOME}"]
```

Answer from sffits [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5509).

Comment: my problem with this is that I am trying to add ssl parameters to postgres command which is already defined in the alpine base dockerfile. My cmd looks like this CMD [ "-c", "ssl=on" , "-c", "ssl_cert_file=/var/lib/postgresql/postgresdb.crt", "-c",    "ssl_key_file=/var/lib/postgresql/postgresdb.key", "-c",    "ssl_ca_file=/var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crt", "-c", "ssl_crl_file=/var/lib/postgresql/myCA.crl" ] how will you put a variable in this?

Answer (score 14):

Both Andys had it right. The json syntax bypasses the entrypoint. When you use CMD as in their example, it is considered as an argument to the default entrypoint: `/bin/sh -c` which will interpret the environement variables.

Docker does not evaluate the variables in CMD in either case. In the former, the command is directly called so nothing gets interpreted, in the later, the variables are interpreted by `sh`.

Answer (score 9):

I can't speak to how it is *supposed* to work, but I think if you called this as a shell script, e.g. `CMD runmyserver.sh`, then the interpretation of the shell variables would be deferred until the CMD actually ran.

So, try

```
myserver --arg=$ARG --memcache=$MEMCACHE_11211_TCP_ADDR:$MEMCACHE_11211_TCP_PORT``
```

as a shell script?