# How can I use environment variables in JVM startup options without shell expansion

Tags: java, docker

I'd like to use an environment variable to set `-XX:HeapDumpPath` option on JVM startup. Moreover, I'd like this to work inside a Docker container and in such a way that my JVM process gets PID 1. This seems to make all the proposed solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23071214/5738696) question invalid for my case.

My current solution looks like this:

- Dockerfile

  ```
  FROM openjdk:10

  COPY . .

  ENTRYPOINT [ "./start.sh" ]
  ```
- start.sh

  ```bash
  #!/usr/bin/env bash

  exec java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=${HEAP_DUMP_PATH} -jar build/libs/app.jar
  ```

If I build it with `docker build --tag=test .` and then run with `CID=$(docker run --rm -e HEAP_DUMP_PATH="/tmp" -d test) && docker exec $CID ps -f` I get:

> UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
>   root         1     0  0 16:18 ?        00:00:00 java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp -jar build/libs/app.jar
>   root        21     0  0 16:18 ?        00:00:00 ps -f

So it seems to be working. But it also seems unnecessarily complicated. Is there a better/cleaner way to achieve this?

**Update**: removed `-c` in `exec -c`.

Comment: That's a very reasonable way to do it IMHO; you also might see if the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable works for you.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze, but I hope that there exists either a Docker-specific solution for expanding env. variables in `ENTRYPOINT`/`CMD` directives, or a HotSpot-specific solution for expanding env. variables in JVM configuration. Both of the above seem reasonable to me, but maybe I'm missing something. :)