# Expand ARG value in CMD [Dockerfile]

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm passing a build argument into: `docker build --build-arg RUNTIME=test`

In my Dockerfile I want to use the argument's value in the CMD:

`CMD ["npm", "run", "start:${RUNTIME}"]`

Doing so results in this error: `npm ERR! missing script: start:${RUNTIME}` - it's not expanding the variable

I read through this post: [Use environment variables in CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071214/use-environment-variables-in-cmd)

So I tried doing: `CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm run start:${RUNTIME}"]` - I end up with this error: `/bin/sh: [sh,: not found`

Both errors occur when I run the built container.

I'm using the node alpine image as a base. Anyone have ideas how to get the argument value to expand within CMD? Thanks in advance!

full Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.15.0-alpine as builder

ARG RUNTIME_ENV=test
RUN mkdir -p /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY . .

RUN npm ci
RUN npm run build

FROM node:10.15.0-alpine

COPY --from=builder /usr/app/.npmrc /usr/app/package*.json /usr/app/server.js ./
COPY --from=builder  /usr/app/config ./config
COPY --from=builder  /usr/app/build ./build

RUN npm ci --only=production

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:${RUNTIME_ENV}"]
```

Update:
Just for clarity there were two problems I was running into.
1. The problem as described by Samuel P.
2. ENV values are not carried between containers (multi-stage)

Here's the working Dockerfile where I'm able to expand environment variables in CMD:

```
# Here we set the build-arg as an environment variable.
# Setting this in the base image allows each build stage to access it
FROM node:10.15.0-alpine as base
ARG ENV
ENV RUNTIME_ENV=${ENV}

FROM base as builder
RUN mkdir -p /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY . .
RUN npm ci && npm run build

FROM base
COPY --from=builder /usr/app/.npmrc /usr/app/package*.json /usr/app/server.js ./
COPY --from=builder  /usr/app/config ./config
COPY --from=builder  /usr/app/build ./build

RUN npm ci --only=production

EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm run start:${RUNTIME_ENV}
```

Comment: Can you please share your complete Dockerfile?

Comment: Dockerfile has been edited into the post, thanks for checking

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that `ARG` params are available only during image build.

> The ARG instruction defines a variable that users can pass at build-time to the builder with the `docker build` command using the `--build-arg <varname>=<value>` flag.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg

`CMD` is executed at container startup where `ARG` variables aren't available anymore.

`ENV` variables are available during build and also in the container:

> The environment variables set using ENV will persist when a container is run from the resulting image.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

To solve your problem you should transfer the `ARG` variable to an `ENV` variable.

add the following line before your `CMD`:

```
ENV RUNTIME_ENV ${RUNTIME_ENV}
```

If you want to provide a default value you can use the following:

```
ENV RUNTIME_ENV ${RUNTIME_ENV:default_value}
```

[Here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables) are some more details about the usage of `ARG` and `ENV` from the docker docs.