# Dockerfile with parametrization: fails with XXX

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven

I have the following `Dockerfile` in a simple Spring Boot app:

```
FROM maven:3.6-jdk-8-alpine as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./pom.xml ./pom.xml

RUN mvn dependency:go-offline -B

# copy your other files
COPY ./src ./src

# build for release
RUN mvn package -DskipTests

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
ARG artifactid
ARG version
ENV artifact ${artifactid}-${version}.jar
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/target/${artifact} /app

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]

CMD ["java","-jar ${artifact}"]
```

When I build it with the required arguments:

```
docker build --build-arg artifactid=spring-demo --build-arg version=0.0.1 -t spring-demo .
```

it builds with no errors.

When I try to run the image with:

```
docker container run -it spring-demo
```

it fails with the following error:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server   to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server,
                  because you are running on a server-class machine.


    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
```

What's wrong with the above settings, please?
The app example code can be found [here](https://github.com/belgoros/spring-demo).

Comment: Try like this: `CMD ["java", "-jar", "${artifact}"]`

Comment: @MarkoE, It raises the same error

Answer (score 2):

You should delete that `ENTRYPOINT` line and use the shell form of `CMD`.

```sh
# No ENTRYPOINT
CMD java -jar ${artifact}
```

The Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` lines [get combined into a single command line](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  In your Dockerfile, that gets interpreted as

```sh
sh -c java '-jar ${artifact}'
```

But the `sh -c` option only actually takes the next single word and interprets it as the command to run; so that really gets processed as

```sh
sh -c 'java' # '-jar ${artifact}'
```

ignoring the `-jar` option.

There are [two](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) [ways](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) to "spell" `CMD` (and `ENTRYPOINT` and `RUN`).  As you've done it with JSON arrays, you specify exactly the "words" that go into the command line, so for example, `-jar ${artifact}` would be passed as a single argument including the embedded space.  If you just pass a command line, Docker will insert a `sh -c` wrapper for you, and the shell will handle word parsing and variable interpolation.  You shouldn't ever need to manually include `sh -c` in a Dockerfile.

Comment: I removed `ENTRYPOINT` and tried 2 ways: `CMD ["java", "-jar ${artifact}"]` which raised `Unrecognized option: -jar ${artifact}, Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.`. And as follows: `CMD ["java", "-jar", "${artifact}"]`, which raised `Error: Unable to access jarfile ${artifact}`. What am I missing?

Comment: Ah, my bad, -   `CMD java -jar ${artifact}` worked fine :). Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is still unclear for me WHY `CMD ["java", "-jar", "spring-demo-0.0.1.jar"]` works but not when using artifact variable: `CMD ["java", "-jar", "${artifact}"], - it fails with `Error: Unable to access jarfile ${artifact}`. The same when using `CMD ["java", "-jar ${artifact}"]` which raised `Unrecognized option: -jar ${artifact}`. Why so ?

Comment: The JSON-array form doesn't involve a shell at all, and Docker doesn't expand variables in `CMD`.  In the first case you are literally passing the string `${artifact}` as the second option.  In the third, you're combining the two options together and passing `-jar ${artifact}` (with a space, dollar sign, and braces) as a single argument, and the JVM can't make sense of it.

Comment: Same error with `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "${artifact}"]`, it is really weird, IMHO, why the jar being present in the container is not visible neither by `CMD` nor by `ENTRYPOINT`. The only way to make it work is: `CMD java -jar ${artifact`} with no brackets, no quotes.

Comment: Yes.  See the "two ways" links in the answer; the Dockerfile [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) documentation also discusses the differences between the string and JSON-array forms.

Comment: I figured out that I can still use an array version of `ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]` if I use the variable `artifact` in the previous command as follows: `COPY --from=build /app/target/${artifact} app.jar`. This way it is recognized by `COPY` with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you have an error with the `sh -c`. The arguments are not read correctly. You could check that if you do a docker inspect on the exited container. In the output search for the "CMD".

> ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]
>
> CMD ["java","-jar ${artifact}"]

If you would like to run it with `sh -c`, you have to quote the arguments as one like:

`CMD ["java -jar ${artifact}"]`

Can you give it a try?

Comment: Yep, thank you, it worked. I just followed [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/a-dockerfile-for-maven-based-github-projects) where the author used the previous syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`ENV` variables are only available during the build. To get env variables into the container at runtime, you have to use `--env` or `-e` or `--env-file`. It is best to use `--env-file`.

See this for same problem answered already: [How do I pass environment variables to Docker containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers)
Also look at this: [Use environment variables in CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071214/use-environment-variables-in-cmd)

Here is one possible solution:

1. Keep your `CMD` instruction as this:

```
CMD ["java","-jar ${artifact}"]
```

2. Use this docker `run` command:

```
docker container run -it -e artifact=spring-demo-0.0.1.jar spring-demo
```

Comment: The problem is not there, ENV variable is available in the final image compared to `ARG`.