# How can I pass $JAVA_OPTS to my entrypoint as env var?

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to pass JAVA_OPTS to my entrypoint but all syntax that I have tried isn't working. Here is my code:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", $JAVA_OPTS, "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8008", "-cp","app:app/lib/*","gov.aus.mkt.data.MktApp", "--spring.redis.host=redis"]
```

Is there any way to pass `$JAVA_OPTS` from environment variable defined on docker-compose?

While I was searching on internet, I also find some posts about being a bad practice use entrypoint as I am doing. What is the "right" way and why?

edit:

Solved it using explicit exec:

```
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8008 -cp app:app/lib/* gov.aus.mkt.data.MktApp --spring.redis.host=redis
```

Is it a good practice? Why?

Comment: This seems like basically the same question as [Use environment variables in CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071214/use-environment-variables-in-cmd); do the answers there help you?

Comment: I tend to prefer `CMD` over `ENTRYPOINT` for being a little easier to override and for fitting nicely into the entrypoint-wrapper pattern.  A shell-form (bare string) `ENTRYPOINT` can be problematic for completely ignoring the command part (or any arguments passed after the `docker run image-name`).  But that's mostly my opinion, and I've seen commentary preferring `ENTRYPOINT` as well.