# AWS Lambda Docker container - fork/exec no such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile

I am trying to run a Docker container in AWS Lambda using the AWS console. The architecture used is x86_64 and the Docker container runs a Python-based handler function. The Python script `backup_manager.py` that is in the container contains two functions, one helper named `get_parameter`, which extracts parameters from the AWS Parameter Store, and another named `handler`, which executes the code on an event (the `handler` uses the `get_parameter` function).

This is my the Dockerfile:

```
# install Ubuntu 20.04
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# update Ubuntu packages
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install -y apt-utils \ 
           build-essential \
           curl \
           libffi-dev \ 
           libssl-dev \ 
           libxml2-dev \ 
           libxslt1-dev \
           unzip \
           wget \
           zlib1g-dev 

# install Python 3.11
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common gcc && \
    add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.11 python3.11-dev python3.11-distutils python3-pip python3-apt python3.11-venv
 
# make symlink (overriding default Python3.8 installed with Ubuntu)
RUN rm /usr/bin/python3
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3.11 /usr/bin/python3

# create a virtual environment 
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3.11 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

# upgrade pip
RUN python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade pip

# copy files
ARG output_path=${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/mongodb_backups
RUN mkdir $output_path
COPY requirements.txt *.yml $output_path/

# install Python packages
RUN pip3 install -r $output_path/requirements.txt

# download MongoDB Database Tools (architecture x86_64)
ARG archive=mongodb-database-tools-amazon2-x86_64-100.9.1
RUN wget -P ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/ https://fastdl.mongodb.org/tools/db/"${archive}.tgz"
RUN tar -zxvf ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/"${archive}.tgz"

# make the DB Tools available in PATH
RUN cp ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/$archive/bin/* ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/usr/local/bin/

# run main Python script
CMD ["${output_path}/backup_manager.handler"]
```

When I click "Test" in the console, after having deployed the image, I get the following error:

```
Error: fork/exec ${output_path}/backup_manager.handler: no such file or directory
```

The error is quite self-explanatory, but I have double-checked the paths when running the image locally and it appears I am using the correct path when calling the `CMD` command. I have checked online people with similar problems, but there are only a few and I could not fix this issue.

Comment: Does changing it to shell-form syntax (remove the `["..."]` JSON-array syntax) help; [Use environment variables in CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071214/use-environment-variables-in-cmd)?  Since the filesystem paths are fixed in your image you don't really need to use an environment variable here.

Comment: @DavidMaze changing the syntax to shell-form did not help and yielded the same error.

Answer (score 0):

So, I kept searching for a solution to this. There were two immediate issues with my Dockerfile:

1. I forgot to copy the `backup_manager.py` script to the image.
2. Variables created with `ARG` should not be used in the `CMD` command.

That said, I was still running into path issues and I suspect that was something to do with the variable `LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT`, which probably is only created if you using public AWS images. I've managed to make my Dockerfile working in AWS Lambda by using a public Lambda AWS Image for Python 3.11.

```
# install Python 3.11 AWS Lambda image
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11

# install Ubuntu packages
RUN yum install -y wget tar.x86_64 gzip

# copy files
COPY requirements.txt *.yml backup_manager.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/

# install Python packages
RUN pip3 install -r ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/requirements.txt

# download MongoDB Database Tools (architecture x86_64)
ARG archive=mongodb-database-tools-amazon2-x86_64-100.9.1
RUN wget -P ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/ https://fastdl.mongodb.org/tools/db/"${archive}.tgz"
RUN tar -zxvf "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"/"${archive}.tgz"

# make the DB Tools available in PATH
RUN cp ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/$archive/bin/* /usr/local/bin/

# run Lambda function
CMD ["backup_manager.handler"]
```